# How to search for a duplicate in a given string using scriptlet?

Tags: scriptlet

How can I search for a duplicate in a given string using a scriptlet?

```
ScripletInput= a,b,c,a
```

Here the letter 'a' is repeating. If it is repeating more than once, then it should exit, else it can go ahead.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I'm new to this :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear, as you're asking about a tool/language that uses Java, but you accepted an answer that uses JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [Remove occurrences of duplicate words in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843991/remove-occurrences-of-duplicate-words-in-a-string)

The code below will remove duplicates in a string.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    str=prompt("Enter String::","");
    arr=new Array();
    arr=str.split(",");
    unique=new Array();
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        if((i==arr.indexOf(arr[i]))||(arr.indexOf(arr[i])==arr.lastIndexOf(arr[i])))
            unique.push(arr[i]);   
    }
    unique.join(",");
    alert(unique);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time :) Appreciate it. I'm using HP OO and I have to use scriptlet which be in below format

Comment: if (action.match(/aclrequest/)){
  scriptletResponse = "aclrequest";
}
if (action.match(/vlan/)) {
  scriptletResponse = "vlan";
}
if (action.match(/firewall/)) {
  scriptletResponse = "firewall";
}
if (action.match(/Error/)) {
  scriptletResponse = "dataerror";
} ... IS it possible to find duplicate with the snippet provided?