# Unclear Javascript programming pattern (functions). Why the results differ?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function

### **Inside the Chrome Console I have a string:**

```
var string = 'john, john, bob, nina, colin, bob, luck, robert, nina, john, jack';
```

Then it is being modified and assigned to a new value using two, **seeming identical to me**, methods:

### **First method:**

```
var string2 = string.split(", ").filter(function(value, index, array){
    return index === array.indexOf(value);
}).join(', ');
```

### **Second method:**

```
var string3 = string.split(", ").filter(function(value, index, array){
    if(index === array.indexOf(value)) return index;
}).join(', ');
```

### **What should both methods do:**

1. Turn the string into an array of each word separately.
2. Filter the array so that no duplicate values exist.
3. Turn the array back into a string format.

### What **I would expect** values of string2 and string3 to be :

```
"john, bob, tony, nina, colin, luck, robert, jack"
```

They should be strictly identical (based on my logic).

### What I actually get:

```
string2 = "john, bob, tony, nina, colin, luck, robert, jack";
string3 = "bob, tony, nina, colin, luck, robert, jack"
```

"John" is missing in the second string.

### **What I already checked:**

1. The strict comparison (===), that is being performed inside the
   if-statement () is true for the first "john".
2. Both index (parameter
   of the function) and index of the value of the first "john" are
   0 as expected.

### **What I ask:**

Explain, please, why do the results differ?

Comment: The first makes no sense. You have to always return a boolean value from the `filter` predicate function - not sometimes `undefined` and sometimes a number.

Comment: Your "what I actually get" results look like they're reversed.

Comment: 1. I got the function, that is being used for string2 from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843991/remove-occurrences-of-duplicate-words-in-a-string 2. Swapped the functions in the post due to the mistake. Now it is correct.

Comment: Your second method works fine for me, returning no duplicates: `string3 ==
"john, bob, nina, colin, luck, robert, jack"`. I'm not sure where tony came from in your expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second example:

```
var string2 = string.split(", ").filter(function(value, index, array){
    if(index === array.indexOf(value)) return index;
}).join(', ');
```

The line `if(index === array.indexOf(value)) return index;` is wrong.

That will return `index` if `index === array.indexOf(value)`, and nothing if not. You need to return `true` or `false`.

In JavaScript, all numbers except `0` convert to `true`, and `0` converts to `false`. So if the `index` is `0`, you are basically returning `false` instead of `true`.

This is the correct code:

```
var string2 = string.split(", ").filter(function(value, index, array){
    if(index === array.indexOf(value)) return true;
    else return false;
}).join(', ');
```

Comment: the "correct code" is superfluous, in case of just retuning the comparison result.

Comment: @NinaScholz He asked what the difference was. The second one was actually wrong, so by correcting it to what he wanted it to be, they are now basically identical.

Comment: The "correct code" lacks a  `return false` in the `else` case. Relying on `undefined` being a falsy value is just the same bad style the OP fell to.

Comment: it's still a messy code, with `if (...) return true; else return false;`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Obviously. I was correcting his second example so it would still look like his second example. The first example would still be better.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (index === array.indexOf(value)) return index; // returns 0, at index 0,
                                                  // should return true
```

vs

```
return index === array.indexOf(value);
```

It's just the problem in the first case on index zero, you return the index, which is zero and this resolves for [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to `false`, whereas it should be `true`, like in the second case.

Comment: That's the issue! So, I just need to return **value** instead of **index**? Thank you, @Nina Scholz!

Comment: @Eduard No, you should return neither the value nor the index. You should return a boolean.

Comment: @bergi it works if I return the **value** (although, I understand that it is semantically incorrect). So, there is no **correct** way out of this, if I keep using **.fiter()**. Should I then swap the **.filter()** function for something else?

Comment: @Eduard You return `true`, check my answer.

Comment: filter expect a boolean value for deciding if an element should go to the result set or not. the comparison with index and indexOf returns a boolean value, which can be used here.

Comment: @Eduard returning the `value` might work in your specific case, but it's not correct. I repeat: `filter` expects the callback to return a boolean (true or false). Anything else will be cast to one. And falsy values (like the `index` 0, or a empty string `value`) will mess up the result. So just use `return check`, or `if (check) return true; else return false;` if you insist on an `if` statement.

Comment: @Bergi Got you! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

<s>Your results are reversed. The first code block is the one that eliminates "John".</s> *(Question was edited to correct this)*

For `string3`, it eliminates "John" because the only time it will return an index for "John" is when "John" is at index `0`, and that's a falsey value, so "John" will not be included in the result.

It's clearer if you return a boolean value, like in the working example, so you don't need to deal with issues when the value itself is falsey.