# Replace all of the the same word in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Say I have a string: `var str="localhost:20012/prj/duck/duck/woohoo"`.

As you might have noticed there is 2 `/duck` at the above string. FYI: There could be more.

What I basically Want is to remove all and just leave want so its gonna look like: `localhost:20012/prj/duck/woohoo`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843991/remove-occurrences-of-duplicate-words-in-a-string

Comment: @Whatever, it is working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` method and then just remove the duplicates using `filter` method by passing a callback provided function.

```js
var str="localhost:20012/prj/duck/duck/woohoo";
str=str.split('/').filter(function(item,index,str){
  return str.indexOf(item)==index;
}).join('/');
console.log(str);
```