# How to delete duplicate from string

Tags: javascript

How to remove duplicate from string for example

```
const string = 'PandoraPandora'; to --> Pandora
```

OR

```
const string = 'pandorapandora'; to --> pandora
```

Note: string doesn't have spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove occurrences of duplicate words in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843991/remove-occurrences-of-duplicate-words-in-a-string)

Comment: Hmm it depends on which scenarios you want to support. Is there a minimum character count for repetition to remove?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit] the question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Also please see **[ask]**

Comment: Is it always a sting like "wordword" or could it be more complex?

Comment: @Teun it's *not* a duplicate because you can't do 'Split by spaces' here (or any other separator).

Comment: Voilà `string.slice(0, string.length/2)`

Comment: @ponury-kostek Thank you very much its help ;)

Comment: @MatthewJohnMiernik you welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
const str = 'pandorapandora'
const midIndex = Math.floor(str.length/2)
const firstHalf = str.slice(0,midIndex)
const secondHalf = str.slice(midIndex)
const dup = firstHalf == secondHalf ? firstHalf : str
console.log(dup)
```